# QtSDK first compile error

Tags: qt

I've downloaded the QtSDK for windows and installed it.

I'm using QtCreator to run their test program but run into this problem:

```
17:03:30: Running build steps for project keepintouch...
17:03:30: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
17:03:30: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/QtSDK/Examples/QtMobility/keepintouch-  build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug2'
g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL - DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN  - I"..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include" -I"..\..\src\messaging" -I"..\..\src\contacts" -I"..\..\src\contacts\details" -I"..\..\src\contacts\filters" -I"..\..\src\contacts\requests" -I"..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\keepintouch" -I"." -I"..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\addressfinder.o ..\keepintouch\addressfinder.cpp
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/QtSDK/Examples/QtMobility/keepintouch-build-  desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug2'
 mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug/addressfinder.o] Error 1
 mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
 17:03:31: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
 Error while building project keepintouch (target: Desktop)
 When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: The actual error is earlier in that log, you're only showing Make reporting that an error occured.

Comment: Ah sorry. I've included it now.

Comment: There's a strange space in the compile command: `...   - I"..\...` there should be no space between the `-` and `I`. Other than that, the actual error isn't showing. Does your compiler work?

Comment: That space was accidentally caused when I copied the error message here. I don't know if my compiler works because it came with the SDK (although I use the same compiler Mingw in codeblocks).